# Group only rows that have some properties and others keep as single row in ag-grid

Tags: javascript, angular, grid, ag-grid

I have a rowData like this

```
[
    {key: income, ...},
    {key: sumIncome, ...},
    {key: cost, ...},
    {key: sumCost, ...},
    {key: total, ...},
]
```

Here, I need to only group that has keys as income and cost. other rows should keep as single rows in that position.

for now, I use  `groupRemoveSingleChildren: true,` property in the **grid option** and it is working only below the object array.

```
[
    {key: income, ...},
    {key: income, ...},
    {key: sumIncome, ...},
    {key: cost, ...},
    {key: cost, ...},
    {key: sumCost, ...},
    {key: total, ...},
]
```

So when I have one value for income and cost like the first array object, I can't get the behavior that I want. Any solution to get this thing done?